# Multipart Upload using Google Drive iOS sdk

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

How can I sync very big files like Video files to Google drive using GTLServiceDrive service? I know that sync is possible using queryForFilesInsertWithObject:uploadParameters: method. But here I pass  data as a parameter of GTLUploadParameters object. But if I am uploading big files, I cannot hold the whole object in memory. Does Google drive ios sdk supports multi-part upload? If Yes, can someone point me how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading the file contents into a `NSData` instance you can configure your upload parameters to use a `NSFileHandle` to the file you want to upload. The SDK will upload the file in chunks.

```
NSString *filePath = @"/path/to/file";
NSString *mimeType = @"text/plain";
NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];
GTLUploadParameter *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithFileHandle:file
                                                                             MIMEType:mimeType];
```

[Official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/files) here.